# Parse Passing PFUser to Watch Extension

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to pass the PFUser.currentUser() object to the apple watch extension to load some data. I know that I can do it with App Groups, but this requires the activation of local data store and I need to use cache. So I implemented this code in the app delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {
    // retrieved parameters from Apple Watch
    //println(userInfo["value1"])
    //println(userInfo["value2"])

    // pass back values to Apple Watch
    var retValues = Dictionary<String,PFUser>()

    retValues["retVal1"] = PFUser.currentUser()!

    print(PFUser.currentUser()!)

    reply(retValues)
}
```

However the app crashes and says that the value of the currentUser is nil: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
func getCurrentUser(){
    var dict = ["test" : 4] //your dictionary/request to sent to the iPhone
    if !WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(dict, reply: { (reply,error) -> Void in
        println("\(reply)") //your reply data as Dictionary

        if let passedCurrentUser: PFUser = reply["currentUser"] as? PFUser{
            self.currentUser = passedCurrentUser
            self.getTrips()
        }

    }) {
        println("ERROR")
    }
}
```

PFUser.currentUser() is clearly not nil. The data is not even printed with the print method print(PFUser.currentUser()!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out an easier way to do it, using App Groups:

1) Enable App Groups both on the Watch target and your App

2) Go in the AppDelegate and insert:

```
let appGroupID = "group.com.xx"
let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: appGroupID)
defaults!.setObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId, forKey: "theCurrentUser")
```

3) In the watch extension:

```
let appGroupID = "group.com.xx"
let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: appGroupID)
if let theCurrentUser = defaults?.stringForKey("theCurrentUser") {
  //do something
}
```